# Infinite loop in angularjs ng-if

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, loops

Using the https://github.com/ironboy/mongresto framework, I have an angularjs directive with html and js. The problem is the `Assignment.get` is looping 2000+ times which makes me think something is wrong with my implementation of ng-if as this calls the `scope.hasAssignment`. Or maybe im looking in the wrong place

**assignments.html**

```
<!--Assignments-->
   <li ng-if = "hasAssignment(course.assignments)"><a  ng-click="isChildOpen = !isChildOpen">Assignments <i ng-hide="isChildOpen" class="fa--toggle fa fa-chevron-right"></i><i ng-show="isChildOpen" class="fa--toggle fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
   <ul ng-show="isChildOpen" ng-repeat="assignment in assignmentlist">
       <li><a href="courses/{{course.name}}/assignment/{{ assignment._id }}"><i class="fa--itemtype fa fa-file-text-o"></i>{{assignment.name}}</a></li>
   </ul>
```

**assignments.js**

```
scope.hasAssignment = function(assignmentArray) 
     {
         if(typeof assignmentArray !== 'undefined' && assignmentArray.length > 0)
          {                
              Assignment.get({course: scope.course._id}, function(res){
                 scope.assignmentlist = res;
              });
              return true;
          }
          else
          {
              return false;
          }
     }
```

I used a console log on the `assignmentArray` passed into the function and it returns an array of 3 assignments. The functionality works in the end, and the list gets filled with results from the db its just it keeps running forever.

Comment: You are having `hasAssignment` inside ng-if` which is getting call on each digest cycle, from that function you are again calling `Assignment.get` which again run an digest cycle once it get completed.. so this is scenario is happening infinite amount of time & that is causing an error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set it in your `ngIf` directive, it gets evaluated on each `$digest` cycle, which gets called in many situations, including model changes. So, whenever you make an AJAX call (which is async), the update of `scope.assignmentlist = res;` triggers another `$digest` cycle that in turn makes another call and so on... But even on first load, the `$digest` cycle will run several times, each of which will make a call, triggering the infinite loop of requests... For a deeper understanding of the `$digest` cycle, read [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/) article.

So, in order to get rid of this infinite loop, you can check against the `.length` condition in your ngIf:

```
<li ng-if = "course.assignments && course.assignments.length"><a  ng-click="isChildOpen = !isChildOpen">Assignments <i ng-hide="isChildOpen" class="fa--toggle fa fa-chevron-right"></i><i ng-show="isChildOpen" class="fa--toggle fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
```

First, you check whether the course assignments is defined and then if it has a length. And in your controller make the `Assignment.get` call in some other place (this depends on your program logic. In most cases, you can do this on controller initialization).